# Change default font and remove bloatware without rooting the phone

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lenovo

I have Lenovo S90 and I want to change the system default font and to delete some pre installed applications as well. Based on my initial research, the only possible way on how I can do what I want is by rooting my phone. My system is already running at Android 5.0.2 Lollipop. I was reading online tutorials about rooting this device and found them really troublesome and complicated as I am not a "techie" type of a person.
Is there a possible way that you can suggest with regards tot his matter?  Would appreciate your response a lot. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *deleting* pre-installed apps? You can disable them, but uninstalling seems impossible. One needs root privilege to do that.

Comment: Indicate clearly what you found troublesome so that we avoid suggesting in that same manner.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the System font <strike>is</strike> may be an option without root. A quick [Google Search](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=Android+Change+system+font+on+root&rlz=1CAHPZV_enNZ649NZ649&oq=Android+Change+system+font+on+root&aqs=chrome..69i57l2j69i65l3j69i60.6912j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=Android+Change+system+font+no+root) will help with that.

As for *removing* (or "deleting" as you put it) System Apps, you **must** have root, this I can not stress enough. Like @Frank said in the comments, you can *disable* and app, but this is still on your System and it still takes space.

**My advice to you:**

```
    If you don't feel safe about rooting at this time, don't do it.
    If you hate the pre-installed apps so much (my main reason to first root)
    Make a backup and root away! (Keyword: backup)!
```

**Why you need root:**

Mostly to protect the system. Suppose you could uninstall system apps without root. What happens if you mistakenly remove an important part of the system? You now have a broken Android - And imagine if everyone had broken Androids! People would claim Warranty and that cost money, time and effort. That is part of the reason Rooting (as far as I know) will void your warranty.

Comment: Why must you have root access to remove system apps? Can you shed some light on it?